# Updating date field with min date from selected dates if they are >= to current_date, except when all dates are >= to current date

Tags: postgresql, sql-update

I would like to update the contents of the Date1 column to reflect the oldest date in each row, unless the date has already passed (Date1 < current date), in which case i'd like Date1 to be populated with the 2nd oldest date in the row.

| ID | Date 1 | Date 2 | Date 3 | Date 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 01/14/2022 | 01/14/2022 | 01/15/2022 | 01/16/2022 |
| 002 | 04/15/2019 | 04/15/2019 | 01/10/2021 | 01/10/2021 |

I am currently using

```
    update mytable t
    set date1 = (
        select min(date)
        from (values (date2), (date3), (date4)) d(dt)
        where dt >= current_date    
)
```

The only problem I run into is when **all** available dates are prior to the current date. In this case it overwrites the value in the date1 column with null, which is not ideal. I'd like the query to leave the date1 field intact in these instances.

Comment: Please tell us more about what software you are using? Postgres and SQL?

Comment: Yes, I'm using PostgreSQL in PgAdmin 4.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

```
   update mytable t
    set date1 = coalesce ((
        select min(date)
        from (values (date2), (date3), (date4)) d(dt)
        where dt >= current_date    
), date 1);
```